# MySQL query executing but not being recognized in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2008

I have an application that uses a class to create a complete MySQL database for use by the application. The class uses a separate method for creating each table.

A dialog is used to allow the creation of the tables since there are tables for different uses that are created in groups. The underlying code for each group create button executes the table creation methods from the class mentioned above in succession.

Each table creation method uses two queries. The first is

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tablename

The second query is the table definition CREATE TABLE ...

If the database is empty, the tables are all created successfully.

If the tables exist and I'm recreating the tables from scratch, I receive an error (errno 121) when trying to recreate the tables. This is curious since NONE of the tables being recreated have a PRIMARY KEY and NONE have a foreign key! I'm assuming that the errno 121 coming up because the table still appears to be there even though it's been dropped.

If I drop the tables manually using MySQL Workbench and run the table creation again, all is well and all the tables are created successfully again.

It would appear that the DROP TABLE query is not being completed or visible to the program before the CREATE TABLE query is being run. The DROP TABLE is eventually successful because the table no longer appears in the database when I check in MySQL Workbench.

I use the same MySQL command object to run both queries. After execution of the DROP TABLE query, I change the CommandText property for the CREATE TABLE query. I've also tried this with a different MySQL command object with a different MySQL connection object with the same results.

Any idea why the DROP TABLE query is not being completed or recognized before the CREATE TABLE query?

I'm running MySQL 5.1.39 on Windows 8 (same results on Windows 7) with MySQL Connector/NET 6.5.4 in Visual Studio 2008 in C#.

As requested by SH below, here is the code for one of the tables (a small one). The connection string includes the default catalog so I don't have to include it explicitly in the query. This version wraps the queries in a transaction while the original didn't--same results. I even threw in DoEvents as a shot in the dark.

```
    public void CreateViewTableCasualtyLookup()
    {
        // Declare local variables.
        string strSQL = string.Empty;
        string strMsg = string.Empty;
        string strNewDBName = string.Empty;
        MySqlConnection cnNewTable = new MySqlConnection();
        MySqlCommand cmdNewTable = new MySqlCommand();
        MySqlTransaction tranNewTable = null;
        StringBuilder sbSQL = new StringBuilder();

        try
        {
            // Create a connection.
            cnNewTable.ConnectionString = m_strServerConnect;
            cnNewTable.Open();
            cmdNewTable.Connection = cnNewTable;
            tranNewTable = cnNewTable.BeginTransaction();

            // First we need to drop the exising table.
            strSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS vCasualtyLookup";
            cmdNewTable.CommandText = strSQL;
            cmdNewTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tranNewTable.Commit();
            Application.DoEvents();

            // Create the new table.
            tranNewTable = cnNewTable.BeginTransaction();
            sbSQL.AppendLine("CREATE TABLE vCasualtyLookup (");
            sbSQL.AppendLine("CasualtyID char(10), ");
            sbSQL.AppendLine("LookupName varchar(100)) ");
            // sbSQL.AppendLine("PRIMARY KEY (LookupName))");
            sbSQL.AppendLine(" ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci");
            cmdNewTable.CommandText = sbSQL.ToString();
            cmdNewTable.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tranNewTable.Commit();
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tranNewTable.Rollback();
            strMsg = "Application Error:\r\n";
            strMsg += "An error occurred while trying to create the view table vCasualtyLookup. ";
            strMsg += "The full text of the error is shown below:\r\n\r\n";
            strMsg += ex.Message;
            throw new ApplicationException(strMsg);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear objects from memory.
            if (tranNewTable != null)
            {
                tranNewTable.Dispose();
            }
            if (cmdNewTable != null)
            {
                cmdNewTable.Dispose();
            }
            if (cnNewTable != null)
            {
                if (cnNewTable.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    cnNewTable.Close();
                }
                cnNewTable.Dispose();
            }
            if (sbSQL != null)
            {
                sbSQL = null;
            }
        }
    }       // end CreateViewTableCasualtyLookup
```

When this and the methods for other tables are executed, MySQL Workbench reports that the DROP TABLE must have completed because the table is no longer there. When the CREATE TABLE is executed, it generates an exception:

"Can't create table `casualtyutf8.vCasualtyLookup` (errno 121)"

Inspecting the ex variable in the Locals window shows the "base" error code is  "-2147467259" and the MySQL exception "Number" is "1005".

I just checked the MySQL Error Log File which shows:

```
InnoDB: Warning: MySQL is trying to drop table  `casualtyutf8`.`vcasualtyassignnarratives`
InnoDB: though there are still open handles to it.
InnoDB: Adding the table to the background drop queue.
```

The next entry is an INNODB error that the table already exists. I have no idea what other process could have open handles to the table unless it's the Visual Studio debugger. I closed the app and closed Visual Studio but that didn't do anything.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Transaction problems somehow? Connection pooling maybe on the same transaction. This is half a guess.
Also, possibly internal caching of the command, try creating a new MySql Command.

Comment: Tried using a new MySQL Command and a new MySQL Connection so that both are running in separate spaces but that made no difference whatever. I don't have these queries wrapped in a transaction and will try that with a Commit after each. Hard drive write caching has been turned off but that didn't help either. These queries always work without problem when executed simultaneously in MysQL Workbench. Not sure what to look at next.

Comment: Break after the first command and manually inspect the database. See what mysql workbench shows.
Also, show the SQL for the create and drop.

Comment: Added this info in edits above.

Comment: --What is the rest of your code. Is there deferred processing or async processing. (`Application.DoEvents();`)
--Try and run just to drop section of the code on a new clean database that nothing else connects towards, but the test code.
See if you still get the same error as you got above. We are trying to isolate the error as best as you can.

Comment: There's no deferred processing or async processing. When I step through the code, the next line won't execute until the DROP query executes. The entire class is made up of methods for each table like the one shown. The only difference is the CREATE TABLE which is specific for each table. I'll try a clean database and we'll see. This is driving me completely nuts!

Answer (score 0):

OK, this one belongs to the Twilight Zone!

SH suggested I try with a clean new database. So, I created a new schema and created all the tables, views, triggers and routines that exist in the database causing problems. I then populated all the tables in the new database with the exact same data from the old database. This was all done with my application's features.

I ran the code that caused consistent problems against the new database and everything worked fine. I could run the code to rebuild tables ad nauseum and never received an error. I was also able to run the update dialog which alters selected tables to add a new column without problem.

Just for completeness, I dropped the original schema and recreated it from scratch the same way as the new test schema along with all the tables, views, triggers and routines and copied the data back from the test table. Everything ran just fine again and I can't generate any errors any more.

It's obvious that there was some issue with the schema definition of the original database since problems occurred with many tables. When I built my Windows 8 system, I migrated the schemas from my old Windows 7 environment using PhpMyAdmin Export and loading them into Windows 8 using MySQL Workbench. MysQL server version is the same on Windows 8 and Windows 7. Perhaps there was something missed or a glitch of some sort between the export and import. I'll never know.

This is all working now and I appreciate SH's comments and suggestions.

I'll throw this one into the same pile as the Word document that always caused a BSOD -- even for Microsoft! and the Oracle database that would cause the BSOD during testing until we removed user ID 666! and the class that consistently returned an incorrect result until I copied it exactly to a new class where it returned the correct result!

Answer (score 0):

*Collated information From Comments*

Problem: Table was not being deleted properly. The delete appeared to have been deferred for some unknown reason.

```
Troubleshooting Methods used:
Use new MySQL Command in code -> No Change.
Break After First Drop command -> No Change
Check Mysql Logs after first Command -> Locate Error and code.
Verfiy there is no async commands lingering in code -> No Change.
Recreate Error on clean Mysql Db. -> Unrepeatable
```

Solution: Recreate full schema. Error likely caused by MySql Migration of some sort.

OP: Info

> It's obvious that there was some issue with the schema definition of
>   the original database since problems occurred with many tables. When I
>   built my Windows 8 system, I migrated the schemas from my old Windows
>   7 environment using PhpMyAdmin Export and loading them into Windows 8
>   using MySQL Workbench. MysQL server version is the same on Windows 8
>   and Windows 7. Perhaps there was something missed or a glitch of some
>   sort between the export and import. I'll never know.

Answer (score 0):

If your MySQL server is running as a Windows service, it might be helpful to disable it, and run the MySQL server daemon from the console instead.

I had a case when I was seeing:

> "MySQL is trying to drop table `Table` ...InnoDB: though there are
>   still open handles to it."

Errors in the MySQL error log file. I realised that MySQL was installed as a Windows service and it was stuck at the state of 'stopping'. My solution was to reboot the PC, so that I could completely disable the Windows service and run the MySQL daemon from the console.